# intellij - how can I see a lot more compilation errors in each build

Tags: layout, intellij-idea

another intellij question regarding a feature I had in eclipse and missing in intellij.

I don't like the fact that after the build process i see only just a few compilation errors. is there a way to see a lot more (I know it is not possible to see all cause they are correlated but in eclipse i use to see much more).

10x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's compiler feature/limitation, not IDEA. You can probably get more errors by switching to the Eclipse compiler in Settings | Compiler.